# Что нужно добавить в чат-бота чтобы он отвечал не из лс группы а из лс определённого человека?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

У меня есть готовы бот но он отвечает мне в лс группы а мне нужно чтобы он отвечал через мой аккаунт потенциальным клиентам.
P.S. пишу код через питон.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы python-клиент отвечал не через аккаунт бота, а через ваш личный аккаунт, нужно получить для него api_id и hash по ссылке ниже, и запустить клиента с этими данными.

https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id

Пример для telethon:

```
client = TelegramClient('ClientName', api_id, api_hash)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для простых смертных доступ к messages закрыт для обычный страниц. Оставили только для работ с группой. Чтоб получилось работать с сообщениями с личной страницы, надо достать API_ID от официального клиента VK или из Kate Mobile

Comment: А вообще, вот: https://vk.com/dev/messages_api